# mysql avg on multiple inner join

Tags: mysql, inner-join, average

I have the following query:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG( p.price ),2) as Avg_value
FROM quotes 
inner join `system_users`
ON quotes.created_by = system_users.id
inner join quote_items s
ON s.quote_id = quotes.id
inner join new_products p
ON p.id = new_product_id
```

how do you determine what the average is being based on seeing that:
a system user can have many quotes
and a quote can have many quote items
each quote item has one product.

I'd like the average to be based on the number of quotes.
how would the query have to be changed for it to be based on the number of quote_items

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected results to clarify what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes. Please provide a sqlfiddle or DDL equivalent TOGETHER WITH the desired result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly (and I may not be), you are looking for the average price of each quote.  Assuming the quote price is the sum of all of the product prices for that quote, the following query should work.  It first gets the total price for each quote (in the subquery) and then averages it.

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(x.quote_price),2) as Avg_value

FROM

(

SELECT  quotes.id, SUM(p.price) quote_price

FROM    quotes 

        inner join `system_users`
        ON quotes.created_by = system_users.id

        inner join quote_items s
        ON s.quote_id = quotes.id

        inner join new_products p
        ON p.id = new_product_id

GROUP BY quotes.id

) x;
```

Comment: You could also remove the join to the join to the system_users table unless you are using that in your criteria somehow.

Comment: Thanks I am using the system_users table, just left it out of the query for simplicity sakes

Comment: Thanks Tom thats perfect! I am using the system_users table in the where clause. I left it out, it should be: 'Where `system_users`.store_id = 4'. Im just trying to understand why my query is finding the average based on **quote_items** and not quotes as yours is. Thanks again

Comment: Because of the sub-select (the part between the parentheses), my query is taking each quote and summing the price of each of the quote's items to get the total quote price for each quote.  It is *then* taking the quote prices and doing an average of them.  Your query is just taking each item's price and averaging them.